# An efficient way to store <select>'s options in a database?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm making a website where there are thousands of `<select></select>` inputs. their `<option></option>` can be changed dinamicaly by an administrator at any time. I'm actually storing each select input's options on separate tables, associating an Id and a value but this is heavy and not really great because i have ~= 100 tables and i need ~= 100 queries to display all the inputs on one page.

Is there any better storage solution ?

Current table exemple :

```
Table : selectanimaltype

ID     NAME
1       pig
2       cow
3       sheep
4       fox
...     ...
```

And i have a thousands of table like this one

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why do you make table for every new select? Add third field `select_name` and select options by this field.